# How to use/choose/install a Mixed-Integer Nonlinear solver in pyomo

Tags: python-3.x, solver, pyomo

Online I can read that it is posible to solve Mixed-Integer Nonlinear problems with pyomo. But I don´t understand how.
I solved problems with “glpk” and “ipopt” solvers but both don´t work for my current problem (ipopt doesn´t respect a boolean variable). (I also rebuild the problem to avoid the Boolean variable, but in case that the global optimum is at 0 (in one dimension) ipopt only shows me a local optimum far from 0).

I found this paper http://egon.cheme.cmu.edu/Papers/Bernal_Chen_MindtPy_PSE2018Paper.pdf
presenting MindtPy but I didn´t figure out how to install it.
I read about many possible solvers, such as  BARON, ANTIGONE, SCIP, LINDOGLOBAL and COUENNE. But how can I use them in pyomo and if possible without a license or is there another solver that you can recommend that comes with pyomo or anaconda (or easy to install).
Thank a lot in advance

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on a freely available MINLP solver for Pyomo (or AMPL) called APOPT. You can download a version that currently solves [NLP problems in Pyomo (MINLP not yet supported)](https://apopt.com/download.php). It sends the .nl problem to a server and then returns a .sol solution to Pyomo.

I have the interface working with Python Gekko for MINLP problems. This is a preview of the solver performance for Pyomo as well. You can install Gekko with:

`pip install gekko`

Or if you are in a Jupyter notebook, you can install Gekko by running this command in a cell (only needed once):

`!pip install gekko`

Here is an example of an MINLP problem:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO() # Initialize gekko
m.options.SOLVER=1  # APOPT is an MINLP solver

# optional solver settings with APOPT
m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 500', \
                    # minlp iterations with integer solution
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 10', \
                    # nlp sub-problem max iterations
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 50', \
                    # maximum deviation from whole number
                    'minlp_integer_tol 0.05', \
                    # covergence tolerance
                    'minlp_gap_tol 0.01']

# Initialize variables
x1 = m.Var(value=1,lb=1,ub=5)
x2 = m.Var(value=5,lb=1,ub=5)
# Integer constraints for x3 and x4
x3 = m.Var(value=5,lb=1,ub=5,integer=True)
x4 = m.Var(value=1,lb=1,ub=5,integer=True)
# Equations
m.Equation(x1*x2*x3*x4>=25)
m.Equation(x1**2+x2**2+x3**2+x4**2==40)
m.Obj(x1*x4*(x1+x2+x3)+x3) # Objective
m.solve(disp=False) # Solve
print('Results')
print('x1: ' + str(x1.value))
print('x2: ' + str(x2.value))
print('x3: ' + str(x3.value))
print('x4: ' + str(x4.value))
print('Objective: ' + str(m.options.objfcnval))
```

It produces the following output:

```
Results
x1: [1.3589086474]
x2: [4.5992789966]
x3: [4.0]
x4: [1.0]
Objective: 17.532267301
```

Answer (score 1):

MindtPy is distributed with Pyomo in the most recent release (v. 5.6.2). Take a look at the examples [here](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/tree/master/pyomo/contrib/mindtpy/tests) to see how problems can be formulated and solved with MindtPy. The other solvers you mentioned must be installed manually and added to your search path, some of them do require a license. COUENNE is a free, open-source option and you can find the installation instructions [here](https://projects.coin-or.org/Couenne). Search for the homepages of the other solvers to learn about their licensing and how to access them.